# VxWorks : Task Id overwrites to another memory location

Tags: vxworks

I have  an application running on VxWorks 5.5.1
It basically allocates a STL map data structure but in some cases my
main task crashes.
When I monitor via debugger, the allocated size for an STL  map type
variable has the value of another task's ID instead of 8.

So it seems like a task ID and a variable is mixing.

The problem occurs in consecutive start and stop of  main task.
Could it possible, TCB block of a task overwrites an area in memory
Regards

Comment: Correction:
not the task id but there is a pointer showing the stack usage of task(stack high).
STL map type variable has the value of this pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. It was beacuse of an custom debug function. 
Thanks for spending time.